# How to use RandomState with Sklearn RandomizedSearchCV on multiple cores

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, numpy-random

I am puzzled about the right way to use `np.random.RandomState` with `sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV` when running on multiple cores.

I use `RandomState` to generate pseudo-random numbers so that my results are reproducible. I give `RandomizedSearchCV` an instance of `RandomState` and set `n_jobs=-1` so that it uses all six cores.

Running on multiple cores introduces an asynchronous element. I expect that this will cause requests for pseudo-random numbers from the various cores to be made in different orders in different runs. Therefore the different runs should give different results, rather than displaying reproducibility.

But in fact the results are reproducible. For a given value of `n_iter` (i.e., the number of draws from the parameter space), the best hyper-parameter values found are identical from one run to the next. I also get the same values if `n_jobs` is a positive number that is smaller than the number of cores.

To be specific, here is code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, StratifiedKFold, train_test_split

# Use RandomState for reproducibility.
random_state = np.random.RandomState(42)

# Get data. Split it into training and test sets.
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=random_state, stratify=y)

# Prepare for hyper-parameter optimization.
n_iter = 1_000

base_clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(
    random_state=random_state, max_features='sqrt')

param_space = {'learning_rate': stats.uniform(0.05, 0.2),
               'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],
               'subsample': stats.uniform(0.8, 0.2)}

# Generate data folds for cross validation.
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)

# Create the search classifier.
search_clf = RandomizedSearchCV(
    base_clf, param_space, n_iter=n_iter, scoring='f1_weighted', n_jobs=-1, 
    cv=skf, random_state=random_state, return_train_score=False)

# Optimize the hyper-parameters and print the best ones found.
search_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Best params={}'.format(search_clf.best_params_))
```

I have several questions.

1. Why do I get reproducible results despite the asynchronous aspect?
2. The documentation for [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) says about the `random_state` parameter: "Pseudo random number generator state used for random uniform sampling from lists of possible values instead of scipy.stats distributions." Does this mean that it does not affect the distributions in the parameter space? Is the code above sufficient to ensure reproducibility, or do I need to set `np.random.seed()`, or perhaps write something like this:

   ```
   distn_learning_rate = stats.uniform(0.05, 0.2)  
   distn_learning_rate.random_state = random_state  
   distn_subsample = stats.uniform(0.8, 0.2)  
   distn_subsample.random_state = random_state  
   param_space = {'learning_rate': distn_learning_rate,  
                  'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200],  
                  'subsample': distn_subsample}
   ```
3. Overall, is this the correct way to set up `RandomizedSearchCV` for reproducibility?
4. Is using a single instance of `RandomState` ok, or should I use separate instances for `train_test_split`, `GradientBoostingClassifier`, `StratifiedKFold`, and `RandomizedSearchCV`? Also, the documentation of [`np.random.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) says that the seed is set when `RandomState` is initialized. How does this interact with `RandomizedSearchCV` setting the seed?
5. When `n_jobs` is set to use fewer than all the cores, I still see activity on all the cores, though the usage level per core increases and the elapsed time decreases as the number of cores increases. Is this just sklearn and/or macOS optimizing the machine usage?

I am using macOS 10.14.2, Python 3.6.7, Numpy 1.15.4, Scipy 1.1.0, and Sklearn 0.20.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter candidates are generated before passing to the multi-threaded functionality using a [ParameterSampler object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html). So only a single `random_state` is enough for reproducibility of RandomizedSearchCV.

Note that I said `"reproducibility of RandomizedSearchCV"`. For the estimators used inside it (`base_clf` here), each estimator should carry its own `random_state` as you have done.

Now talking about `a single instance of RandomState`, it is perfectly fine for the code which is sequential. Only case to worry is when the multi-processing kicks in. So lets analyze the steps which happen during your program's execution.

1. You set up a `RandomState` object with a seed. It has a state now.
2. Inside `train_test_split`, a `StratifiedShuffleSplit` is used (because you have used `stratify` param) which will use the passed `RandomState` object to split and generate permutations in train and test data. So the internal state of `RandomState` is changed now. But its sequential and nothing to worry.
3. Now you set this `random_state` object in `skf`. But no splitting happens until `fit()` in `RandomizedSearchCV` is called. So state is unchanged.
4. After that, when `search_clf.fit` is called, [the following happens](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L691):

   1. [`_run_search()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L1511) is executed, which will use the `random_state` to generate all the parameter combinations at once (according to given `n_iters`). So still no part of multi-threading is happening, and everything is good.
   2. [`evaluate_candidates()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L695) is called. The interesting part is this:

      ```
      out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
                                                 X, y,
                                                 train=train, test=test,
                                                 parameters=parameters,
                                                 **fit_and_score_kwargs)
                         for parameters, (train, test)
                         in product(candidate_params,
                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
      ```
   3. The part after `parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)` is still sequential which is handled by parent thread.

      - `cv.split()` will use the `random_state` (change its state) to generate train test splits
      - `clone(estimator)` will clone all the parameters of the estimator, (the `random_state` also). So the changed state of `RandomState` from `cv.split` object becomes the base state in `estimator`
      - The above two steps happen multiple times (number of splits x parameter combinations times) from parent thread (without asynchronicity). And each time the original `RandomState` is cloned to serve the estimator. So the results are reproducible.
      - So when the actual multi-threading part is started, the original `RandomState` is not used, but each estimator (thread) will have its own copy of `RandomState`

Hope this is making sense, and answers your question. Scikit-learn [explicitly requests the user](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution) to set up like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

to make entire execution reproducible, but what you are doing will also do.

I am not entirely sure about your last question as I not able to reproduce that on my system. I have 4 cores and when I set `n_jobs=2` or `3` I am only seeing those many cores at 100% and remaining at around 20-30%. My system specs:

```
System:
    python: 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51)  [GCC 7.2.0]
   machine: Linux-4.15.0-20-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid

Python deps:
       pip: 18.1
setuptools: 40.2.0
   sklearn: 0.20.1
     numpy: 1.15.4
     scipy: 1.1.0
    Cython: 0.29
    pandas: 0.23.4
```

Comment: Regarding the final question, I found the answer on the [FAQ page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-does-my-job-use-more-cores-than-specified-with-n-jobs-under-osx-or-linux) that you referenced regarding `np.random.seed`.

Comment: @hsafer Ok. Great. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I have a question though: After executing the randomisedsearchcv all the used cores (n_jobs = -1) do not get release on macOS. Looking into the activity monitor I can see all of them still active. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

On the aspect that it does not use all your cpu cores:

I had the same issue and could resolve it doing two things.

- I had written my own distribution class and realised that due to a problem it was crazy slow. Speeding it up helped.
- I set `pre_dispatch` to something reasonable like `pre_dispatch=10*os.cpu_count()`. I think there the issue was is that it prepares all the data before starting to fit things on other cores.